# No layout preview in Newly Created Android Studio Project

Tags: android

i just created new project after updating Android studio and SDK. This was the issue in 28.0.0 alpha too and now after beta, still facing it. Can some one know the fix.

Here is the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.innovativeapps.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

below is code for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I referred few links like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630511/conflicting-versions-of-the-support-library-because-of-the-firebase-library` but did not get any working solution. How to get blueprint and design view for xml code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591502/6478047

Comment: I know 27 is working fine, I want to use latest API version.

Comment: @Panache I tried all the ways I knew , but I was not successful , please do tell me if you find any answer

Comment: surprising google updated to beta but still left so big issue in it.

Comment: android pie is not in beta any more , it was released yesterday [Check this out](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/introducing-android-9-pie.html)

Comment: downgrade your `compilesdk_version,target_sdk and appcompat`

Comment: yes today I updated my pixel 2 to android 9 and here google is lagging in fixing.

Answer (score 0):

update android studio with implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01' and issue is fixed.